# How to redirect users to their intended page after login or register with old input in laravel?

Tags: laravel, redirect, controller

I am creating forum like feature in my website where there will be a textarea to add answer to the given questions.

Any not logged in users can see this textarea. they can type their answer to submit but once they submit i want to redirect them to login or register page.

Once they login or register, they will get redirected back to the page where they typed their answer earlier, the old text must remain there.

here is my `AnswersController@store`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::check()){
    $input = $request->all();
    $question = Question::where('slug', '=', $request['slug'])->first();
    if ($question) {
        $input['body'] = $request->body;
        $input['slug'] = str_slug($request->body);
        $input['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
        //$input['user_id'] = $question->user_id;
        $input['question_id'] = $question->id;
        $answer = Answer::create($input);

       //$user = User::where('forum_email', 1)->get();

           $user = $question->user()->first();
            if ($user->forum_email == 1) {
                Mail::queue('emails.newAnswerTemplate', ['question' => $question, 'user' => $user], function($message) use ($user){
            $message->to($user->email)->from('ryan@kaloraat.com', 'Ryan')->subject('A new answer has been posted to your question!');
        });
            }


        notify()->flash('<h3>Answer posted successfully</h3>', 'success', ['timer' => 2000]);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
    notify()->flash('<h3>Please log in to reply. Thank you!</h3>', 'error');
        return redirect('login')->withInput();
}
```

I have used notify package to display flash messages.

First I am checking `Auth::check()` then saving the answer to the question based on the question id.

Then the user will get email notification and the flash message with success messege.

But for those not logged in users, I want to redirect them to login page with the message to  log in and once they log in they will get back to the page they were before where they typed the answer.

It is important that the answer they typed must remain there during the entire login or register process.

Here is my `AuthController`

`protected $redirectTo = '/home';`

Here obviously i can not manually change the `home` to something like `questions/slug`. There will be other functions in the applications where they need to get redirected to some other pages such as `users` or `articles` so i think the best bet here is to use laravel's `intended` function

I tried to use `return redirect()->intended();` in `AuthController` but it throws an error saying `AuthController does not exist`.

Can someone help me please!

Comment: have you used `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` in your controller?

Comment: can you set cookie with the key as slug and value as the answer.So on login you can check cookie exists and redirect to respective pages.

Comment: i think u can use value="{{ Input::old('name') }}" ,like <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Somebody Awesome" value="{{ Input::old('name') }}">

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use `auth` middleware in your route or the constructor of your controller.

1) Route:

```
Route::get('/route','AnswersController@store')->middleware(['auth']);
```

2)Constructor:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

### Update:

Try this:

Add a following middleware instead of auth. Explanation inline

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Cookie;
class AuthenticateAndRedirect // Change the name according to your conventions
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) { //check if user is guest
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                //if $request has the body add it to cookie
                if($request->has('body'))
                    Cookie::make('body',$request->body);
                //if $request has the slug add it to cookie
                if ($request->has('slug'))
                    Cookie::make('slug',$request->slug);
                //add more fields you need
                return redirect('auth\login'); //your auth url
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now, register your newly created middleware in your kernel.php as lets say `authPost` (change the name according to your conventions)

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'authPost'  => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateAndRedirect::class,
        //your other middlewares        
    ];
```

Now, in your auth controller, Add the following lines to the specified function

**`getLogin()` :** The method responsible for showing the login form

```
public function getLogin()
{
    if(Input::has('slug')){ //check if input has the slug, i.e. if user has entered the data
        // if yes set the 'from' key in your session,
        if(!session()->has('from')){ // check if the the from is already set i.e. if user is redirected again to your auth controller due to validation failure or login failure
            //if from field is not present, that means that the user is visiting the login route first time. Hence set the from field to your previous URl, i.e. from which URl the request is made
            session()->put('from', url()->previous());
        }
    }

    return view('auth.login');
}
```

**authenticated() :**

```
public function authenticated($request,$user)
{
    // now after authenticating, simply pull the from field and redirect your user there
    return redirect(session()->pull('from',$this->redirectTo));
}
```

Now, in your method where you create the view in the question, check if cookie is set for `body` and `slug` key. Pass the values to the View.
In your view, check if the `slug` and `body fields are`present and set that to your comments text.

Now add the newly created middleware to your route.

```
Route::get('/route','AnswersController@store')->middleware(['authPost']);
```

**P.S.** : I didn't test this, but would do the job for you.

Comment: I am trying to redirect not logged/registered user to his old page with his old input (text) remaining there after login or register process. using `middleware` `auth` is not the solution

Comment: @NarayanDhungel check if this updated method is of any use

Comment: Thanks for your answer, hope others will find it useful. However It looks way long and complicated for me, all i want is to redirect people back to wherever they cam from right after they login or register. by default AuthController has protected $redirectTo = '/home'; , I thought there would be an easy to send people back to where they came from using intended or something. I was planning of redirecting people from many different pages to login and then redirect them back to their original destination but i will rather notify them using flash message to login first :)

Comment: @NarayanDhungel u wanted to store data too.. that's why it got complicated , will try to make it simple...

Comment: Hi jaysinkar, If we dont worry about old data, is there simple way of redirecting users back to their original destination after login using something like intended? by default it always redirects to the page we specify. thanks

Comment: yes.. only implement the `getLogin()` and `authenticated()` methods from my answer

Answer (score 0):

To remove the error 'an error saying AuthController does not exist.' use

```
return redirect()->intended('/profile').
```

the profile is default route if something went wrong.

for your query related to textarea content , i suggest to save the content in cookie and redirect the user to login page, once the user is redirect after successfully login, you can display the content in text area from cookies you earlier created.